# Hackerrank challenge: Let's Echo

Tags: bash

I'm trying to solve the Hackerrank Challenge [Let's Echo](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials-lets-echo), which is supposed to be extremely easy. However, if I simply try the solution

```
echo "HELLO"
```

it fails on the second test case (see below)!

[image]

Any idea what is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your solution. If you click on `Test Case #1` you'll see that it expects an output of `HELLO WORLD`.

If you change your command to `echo "HELLO WORLD"` you will pass the `Test Case #1` but fail the `Test Case #0`.

Poorly designed test, basically. Your `echo` was ok.

Answer (score 2):

Test case 1 checks that the output is "HELLO WORLD". If you type in echo "HELLO WORLD", Test case 1 passes while Test case 0 fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

printf "%s" "HELLO";

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right .echo "HELLO" 
All test case passes